# How to write nested if else in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe and I want to achieve the following conditions:

```
if col1 is not none:
    if col1 > 17:
       return False
    else:
       return True
    return None
```

I have implemented it in the following way:

```
out = out.withColumn('col2', out.withColumn(
        'col2', when(col('col1').isNull(), None).otherwise(
            when(col('col1') > 17, False).otherwise(True)
        )))
```

However when I run this I achieve the following error :

```
  assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: do you really have in your code `withColumn` twice ? or it is a typo ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the typo you made, writting twice the `out.withColumn`.

here is my code :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

a = [
    (None,),
    (16,),
    (18,),
]

b = [
    "col1",
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.withColumn(
    "col2",
    F.when(F.col("col1").isNull(), None).otherwise(
        F.when(F.col("col1") > 17, False).otherwise(True)
    ),
).show()

+----+-----+
|col1| col2|
+----+-----+
|null| null|
|  16| true|
|  18|false|
+----+-----+
```

---

You can also do it a bit differently because you do not need the first `otherwise` or no need to evaluate explicitly the `NULL`:

```py
df.withColumn(
    "col2",
    F.when(F.col("col1").isNull(), None)
    .when(F.col("col1") > 17, False)
    .otherwise(True),
).show()

# OR

df.withColumn(
    "col2", F.when(F.col("col1") > 17, False).when(F.col("col1") <= 17, True)
).show()
```